# How to disable csrf in spring security for only localhost?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, csrf

I have working spring boot application in which csrf is enabled but now I want to disable it only for localhost. any request from other domain must underpass csrf security but for localhost, I want to disable it. how can I achieve that?

I know how to disable it by changing

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf.disable();
    }
}
```

the above code disabled csrf but I want to disable csrf for the only localhost.

Can you please help me?

EDIT: I know how to do it by two profile. Thanks @daren for your detailed answer.

Comment: What do you mean by disabling it on localhost ?

Answer (score 3):

You could use Spring Profiles to achieve what you are looking to do.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

At it's simplest you could have two configurations

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@Profile("!deployed") //Not(!) deployed profile
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf.disable();
    }
}
```

And in deployed regions active the `deployed` profile.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@Profile("deployed")
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf.enable();
    }
}
```

Depending on what security configuration you are doing you could do the inverse of this and active a local profile by default which would do the disabling.

Comment: Not that I know off, profiles are here to handle this sort of scenario. You could do other trickier flags but at the end of the day it would be based around some sort of profile.

Comment: @VishalPatel Another solution is to use muliple Spring Security configurations. The first one only for `localhost` with a custom request matcher.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`CsrfConfigurer#requireCsrfProtectionMatcher`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/CsrfConfigurer.html) method and use a `RequestMatcher` which checks the request local vs remote address e.g.

```java
private RequestMatcher csrfProtectionMatcher() {
    final Set<String> allowedMethods = ImmutableSet.of("GET", "HEAD", "TRACE", "OPTIONS");
    return request -> !allowedMethods.contains(request.getMethod()) && !(request.getLocalAddr().equals(request.getRemoteAddr()));
}
```

Comment: Use as such:
httpSecurity.requestMatcher(csrfProtectionMatcher()).csrf()